# AWS VPC Subnet InvalidSubnet.Range only when using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS VPC with a v4 CIDR of `10.0.0.0/16` (I double-checked that CIDR).

When I try to create a subnet on AWS using the following ansible task

```
ec2_vpc_subnet:
    vpc_id: "vpc-<the-non-default-vpc-id>"
    az: eu-central-1c
    cidr: "10.0.2.0/24"
    state: present
```

then I get a an error:

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSubnet.Range) when calling the CreateSubnet operation: The CIDR '10.0.2.0/24' is invalid.`

However, using the CLI
`aws ec2 create-subnet --vpc-id vpc-<definetly-the-same-as-used-in-ansible> --availability-zone eu-central-1c --cidr-block 10.0.2.0/24`
or the AWS web console is working fine.

What could be the reason for that behavior or am I not using the ansible module correctly?

Comment: That looks odd. Did you check if you get a more detailed error message with `-vv`? I see that the code example in the module doc don't use `""` quotes for the cidr parameter. I don't see why this could be a problem but it's something you could check and rule out easy.

Comment: I've tried it with and without quotes, but with no success. Using -vvv does not give any useful output :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. The example I've posted actually works, but I removed the IPv6-CIDR because I thought that the message was clear about what the problem is (IPv4).

Turns out I had a **typo in the IPv6-CIDR**. So when Ansible/AWS complains about an invalid IPv4 subrange, double-check your IPv6 settings (and always post complete examples on StackExchange ...).